# .Net Copy ID Datafield into a Hyperlink Navigate URL parameter

Tags: .net, hyperlink, datafield

I have a .Net 2.0 project where I'd like to take the value from the ID boundfield and pass that to the query string constructor of a Hyperlink field's navigate URL.

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:hyperlinkfield HeaderText="Page Link" DataTextField="title" text="{0}" navigateurl="~\page.aspx?id={THE ID VALUE}" />
```

So in each row, the link would have the ID of the page in the querystring.

```
<a href="page.aspx?id=1234">
```

I don't know if DataControlField.CloneField Method or CopyProperties might be of any help. Is so, can you post an example of how to use them in this case?

In the codebehind, I do not have any databinding events. I have a Viewstate which is filled from the dataset of a SQL View.

Comment: What is the base of this databound control are you using?  ListView, Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using a GridView control.

Here is an example of how you can achieve what you're trying to do:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID"></asp:BoundField>        
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="page.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ID") %>"><%# Eval("DynamicTitle") %></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: There are two parameters. One is the ID the other is the dynamic title that appears where the Link text goes. Do I have to bind that separately too?

Comment: Your binding occurs once.  Look at it as specifying where to place the values of properties.  See my edit, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:
navigateurl=
'<%# string.Format("~\page.aspx?id={0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID"))%>'

Also ensure that the DataSet is bound to the control from the code behind.

Comment: I get an error that the Hyperlink control does not have a databinding event for the DataBinder.